# DataTables main filter by dropbox <select>

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

I have the columns: Rendering engine, Browser, Platform(s), Engine version, CSS grade

My question is how can make the select filter by : Rendering engine

this is my sample.
https://jsfiddle.net/vremx1gd/1/

I want make this filter works:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>Filter by </option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center"> 4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.9</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.2</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.4</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">312.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">419.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">522.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">420</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td class="center">420.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td class="center">413</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td class="center">8.5</td>
            <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td class="center">3.1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td class="center">3.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td class="center">3.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeU">
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution which is for your exact requirement of having external filter

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/chsemndb/3/)

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$("#sel1").on('change',function() {
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
table.draw();
var filterItem=$(this).val()
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {

          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).children("td:first").text()==filterItem;
        }
    );
    table.draw();
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
table.draw();
});

} );
```

Comment: check I have added another solution which is according to your requirement

Comment: thank you, this is what i looking for, how can have the Dropbox working without the reset button ? thank you

Comment: reset button is for bringing all data back to table

Comment: yeah I can see, but I need click in reset to the dropbox back to work understand? right now the filter just works once after this not anymore :(

Comment: bug is there.I am resolving it

Answer (score 2):

DataTables have inbuilt dropdown filter function, for more info visit [Datatable Docs](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

You can also have filter for single column.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/a2LphL4q/1/) for working code

Js Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            if(column[0]==0){ /* is the first column you want to have dropdown filter */
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()))
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            }
        } );
    }
} );
} );
```

Comment: thanks for the help, will be possible to the select be out of the table? like i should you in the sample? thank you again.

Comment: @Raduken if you want to have data source dynamic through ajax request.Then this is one of the possible way